# create a histogram with a dynamic number of partitions in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, histogram

I have a row x with integers in range 0 < x <= maxX.
To create a histogram with five partitions of equal size I am using the following statement in sqlite

```
select case 
    when x > 0 and x <= 1*((maxX+4)/5) then 1
    when x > 1*((maxX+4)/5) and x <= 2*((maxX+4)/5) then 2
    when x > 2*((maxX+4)/5) and x <= 3*((maxX+4)/5) then 3
    when x > 3*((maxX+4)/5) and x <= 4*((maxX+4)/5) then 4
    else 5 end as category, count(*) as count
from A,B group by category
```

Is there a way to make a "dynamic" query for this in the way that I can create a histogram of n partitions without writing n conditions in the case-statement?

Comment: SQLite doesn't really support variables, so your question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arithmetic to divide the values.  Here is one method.  It essentially takes the ceiling value of `maxX / 5` and uses that to define the partitions:

```
select (case when cast(maxX / params.n as int) = maxX / params.n
             then (x - 1) / (maxX / param.n) 
             else (x - 1) / cast(1 + maxX / params.n as int)
        end) as category, count(*)
from (select 5 as n) params cross join
     A
group by category;
```

The `-1` is because your numbers start at one rather than zero.

Comment: this looks good. however, I noticed errors when x is close to maxX. for example, let maxX = 499, n=2, x=499. then the then-clause is executed and returns 2, allthough there should only be the categories of 0 and 1. I think the problem is that the condition of the when-clause is always met because since both parameters are integers the values are truncated without the cast. after I replaced the condition with   maxX*1.0/params.n = maxX / params.n  it works as wanted for the example with 499/2. I did not check if the results are correct in general.